# Can't connect to wifi from rust

Tags: linux, rust, wifi, gnome, gnome-shell

I'm learning Rust and trying to connect to wifi networks through the code. But, when I try to connect to a network with an incorrect password, I receive the default GNOME connect pop-up, like if I'm trying to connect manually. How can I disable this pop-up?
I'm using [wifi-rs](https://crates.io/crates/wifi-rs) 0.2.2 and the example code to connect. I use Pop!_OS 22.04 with GNOME 42.5.

here's the code:

```rs
match wifi.connect(&ssid, &password) {
    Ok(result) => println!(
        "{}",
        if result == true {
            "Connection Successful."
        } else {
            "Invalid password."
        }
    ),
    Err(err) => println!("The following error occurred: {:?}", err),
}
```

Comment: This could help: https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html

Comment: This wifi-rs crate does nothing more than executing `nmcli device wifi connect <ssid> password <password> ifname wlan0` command for you.

Comment: Tried nmcli directly on the console and the pop-up appeared again. Apparently it's a default Pop!_OS feature, but I didn't found how to disable that...
Thank you for the help!